# Setting splash screen for hybrid project

Tags: ionic-framework, hybrid

I am new to hybrid technology,  currently, I am working on the Ionic Framework with AngularJS & Cordova. My problem is how to set a splash screen for my project. 
The target device of my application is iOS devices(iPhone & iPad).

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Regards,
Deepti Aggarwal

Answer (score 1):

Although I am not sure how to do this solely with Phonegap, the [Monaca](http://monaca.mobi/en/) IDE (cloud) for hybrid development allows you to add splash screens plus they take care of the dimensions for you. I would highly recommend an online IDE for hybrid development. Moreover, Monaca allows for free requests to and from their server where you can store data. They integrate [Onsen UI](http://onsen.io/); however, you can still import the Ionic Framework if you like.

Sorry I don't know exactly how to do this. Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to Hybrid application, then use the INTEL XDK for developing your application. Download the SDK and create a new project and you can edit the index.html page in the www folder. After completing the coding, you can build your android/ios/windows/chrome/web application by selecting the build tab and provide certificates and build with just click start building. Hope this helps you. Also, you can add a splash screen by just upload the screen.

Answer (score 0):

1. Save a splash.png, splash.psd or splash.ai file within the resources directory at the root of the Cordova project (minimum size: 2208x2208 px)
2. Generate your splash screen: `ionic resources --splash`